# Running a loop inside if statement

Tags: r

I have a data

```
x$buy_indicator <- c("HOLD","BUY","BUY","HOLD","HOLD","BUY","BUY","HOLD")
x$sell_indicator <- c("HOLD","HOLD","SELL","SELL","HOLD","SELL","SELL","HOLD")
```

I want my output data in such a way that when `buy_indicator=BUY` and `sell_indicator=SELL`, it should change into `HOLD` in both the indicators

My R code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
if(x$Buy_indicator[i]=="BUY" & x$Sell_indicator[i]=="SELL") {x$Buy_indicator[i]=="HOLD" & x$Sell_indicator[i]=="HOLD"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could create a logical vector to find rows where the values need to change

```
x[x$buy_indicator == "BUY" & x$sell_indicator == "SELL", ] <- "HOLD"


x
#  buy_indicator sell_indicator
#1          HOLD           HOLD
#2           BUY           HOLD
#3          HOLD           HOLD
#4          HOLD           SELL
#5          HOLD           HOLD
#6          HOLD           HOLD
#7          HOLD           HOLD
#8          HOLD           HOLD
```

---

If you have other columns than `buy_indicator` and `sell_indicator` you can also subset columns

```
x[x$buy_indicator == "BUY" & x$sell_indicator == "SELL", 
            c("buy_indicator", "sell_indicator")] <- "HOLD"
```

**data**

```
x <- data.frame(
      buy_indicator = c("HOLD","BUY","BUY","HOLD","HOLD","BUY","BUY","HOLD"), 
      sell_indicator = c("HOLD","HOLD","SELL","SELL","HOLD","SELL","SELL","HOLD"))
```